# Avoid prompting users to redial when PPTP connection has been disconnected

Tags: c++, windows, vpn, pptp, ras

I am establishing PPTP connection to the remote server programmatically using RAS api in Windows. The problem is that when server disconnects (for example server stopped) windows automatically prompts user to redial (see screenshot), I don't want this prompt to be shown since my app handles everything by itself but couldn't find any options in RASENTRY to do so. This behavior occurs only on Windows 7, how this could be solved?

[image: screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the RASEO2_ReconnectIfDropped  option that I used for creating a connection. After removing it - prompt does not appear.